# Почему Flex-контейнер не растягивается автоматически на всю свободную ширину?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, flexbox

На форумах и в статьях я читал, что разница между flex и inline-flex контейнерами такая же как и между block и inline-block контейнерами, то есть в лишь в том, что block растягивается на всю оставшуюся ширину, а inline занимает лишь необходимое ему место.
**Вопрос:**  Так почему же если Flex-контейнер (display: flex) является блочным элементом, тогда он не растягивается на всю свободную ширину автоматически?

Comment: а почему ты решил, что он не растягивается на всю свободную ширину автоматически?

Answer (score 2):

**Вопрос:**

> Так почему же если Flex-контейнер (display: flex) является блочным
>   элементом, тогда он не растягивается на всю свободную ширину
>   автоматически?

**Ответ:**

```css
.flex {display: flex; background-color: lightblue;}
.block {display: block; background-color: beige;}
```

```html
<div class="flex">flex</div>
<div class="block">block</div>
```

Но это в том случае, если в блоке будет содержимое.

А если содержимого нет, то:

```css
.flex {display: flex; background-color: lightblue;}
.block {display: block; background-color: beige;}
```

```html
<div class="flex"></div>
<div class="block"></div>
```

Добавим высоту:

```css
.flex {display: flex; background-color: lightblue; height: 20px;}
.block {display: block; background-color: beige; height: 20px;}
```

```html
<div class="flex"></div>
<div class="block"></div>
```

**Вывод:**

В нашем случае никакой разницы между `display: block` и `display: flex` нет.

Comment: Но почему flex элемент не растягивается на всю ширину если, например, слева от него находится какой-то flex элемент. К примеру, у меня есть левый sidebar определенной ширины и контентная часть. Контент не будет растягиваться на всю оставшуюся ширину, если не прописать flex-grow: 1. Почему так?

Answer (score 0):

Flex это для flexible page design, и он растягивается, вот [пруф](https://jsfiddle.net/jcz7r2Lp/1/).

По моему опыту, flex удобно использовать, например, при выравнивании блоков одного размера при адаптивном дизайне, например чтобы 2 divs были одной высоты и т.д. Вообще для каждого свойства `display` есть [свое назначение](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp). 
Прикол `flex` в том, что он подстаивается под контент, который в нем.

- есть еще `flex-direction` проверь [тут](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_flex-direction.asp)

P.S. не эксперт, но довольно часто пользуюсь `flex`. И кстати, в safari он `display:-webkit-flex`